# Custom module name is not displayed with autoclass

Tags: documentation, python-sphinx, python-module, python-packaging

I am building docs with `sphinx` and one of my .rst files has the following content:

```
############
Internal API
############

.. autoclass:: Individual::Individual
    :noindex:
    :special-members:
    :exclude-members: __weakref__
    :member-order: bysource
    :members:

.. autoclass:: exceptions::Error
    :noindex:
    :special-members:
    :exclude-members: __weakref__
    :member-order: bysource
    :members:

.. autoclass:: exceptions::IncorrectValueError
    :noindex:
    :special-members:
    :exclude-members: __weakref__
    :member-order: bysource
    :members:
```

The build is successful, but please take a look at the attached screenshot: [image: pic]

The problem is that the `Individual` class is properly prefixed with `Individual` module name whereas the two latter classes which reside in *exceptions.py* - are not. Why is this happening and how should I fix it?

Edit: I add the contents of my `conf.py` below (without unnecessary parts):

```
import os
import sys
import sphinx_rtd_theme
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../moranpycess'))
extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.napoleon',
    'sphinx_rtd_theme',
    'recommonmark',
]
templates_path = ['_templates']
exclude_patterns = ['_build', 'Thumbs.db', '.DS_Store']
html_theme = 'sphinx_rtd_theme'
html_show_sourcelink = False
html_static_path = ['_static']
```

As well as the contents of `exceptions.py`

```
class Error(Exception):
    """Base class for other exceptions.

    Args:
        Exception (Exception): built-in Exception class
    """

    pass

class IncorrectValueError(Error):
    """Handling incorrect values of user's arguments.

    Args:
        Error (Error): Base class for other exceptions.
    """

    def __init__(
        self,
        parameter,
        message="Please check the documentation for expected argument values.",
    ):
        """Class initializer.

        Args:
            parameter (str): parameter name
            message (str, optional): error message.
                Defaults to "Please check the documentation
                for expected argument values.".
        """
        self.parameter = parameter
        self.message = message
        super().__init__(self.message)

    def __str__(self):
        """Display the error message.

        Returns:
            str: error message
        """
        return f"Incorrect value for {self.parameter}. {self.message}"
```

Comment: There are several errors in your autodoc directives.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense trying to explain what's wrong without the Python code being included. Please edit the question to add a [*"Minimal, Reproducible, Example."*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Basically you are asking us to infer your Python code by looking at the HTML output. There are just too many errors to address in the `.rst` to also have to infer the Python source.

Comment: @bad_coder : I have included the code as well as config for sphinx. What are those many errors in .rst file?

Comment: I can reproduce this. The name `exceptions.py` seems to be "special" in some way. If I change it to, say, `exceptions1.py`, the class names are prefixed with `exceptions1.` in the output.

Comment: thanks a lot @mzjn, I confirm that this 'solution' works for me too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was indeed a special case of a reserved name in `sphinx`:
https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/9280

It shall be fixed in the new release.